# Why can't I use my Gyarados in Pokemon Stadium?

Tags: pokemon-stadium, pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

Using a Pokemon Blue cartridge.

Trying to play 25-30 league, my other pokemon in that level range show up but no Gyarados. He's level 28.

Does Gyarados not exist in Stadium?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia article on Pokemon Stadium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pok%C3%A9mon_Stadium) , the Petit cup is more restrictive than just level:

> Petit Cup: Battle using Basic Pokémon from levels 25 to 30 who fall under a certain height and weight. The most restrictive Cup.

Not only that, but it turns out you can't even use evolved pokemon. Gyrados breaks more than one rule. I think you'll find many of your pokemon aren't selectable for this event.

The rules for the Petit Cup can be seen [here on IGN](http://faqs.ign.com/articles/387/387658p1.html):

> 1. Blue Panels (Qualifying Pokemon): 45 Description: Press A when you
>      highlight this rule, and it will bring
>      up a list of Pokemon. Pokemon in blue
>      boxes can be used but ones in red
>      boxes cannot.
> 2. Enter with six Pokemon. Description: Choose six Pokemon before
>      going to battle. You may not choose 
>      more than one of a certain kind of
>      Pokemon.
> 3. Choose three out of six Pokemon. Description: Out of the six Pokemon
>      chosen, choose the three that are to
>      be  used in battle. Try to choose the
>      three battle Pokemon that have
>      advantages  over the likely opponents.
> 4. Levels 25 to 30. Description: Pokemon of levels 25 to 30 may be
>      used. If you don't have six  Pokemon,
>      you may add Rental Pokemon.
> 5. Maximum three-Pokemon level total 80 Description: The combined levels of
>      the three battle Pokemon may not
>      exceed 
>      80.
> 6. **Max. HT 6' 8'' and max. WT 44 lbs. Description: The height of Pokemon may
>      not exceed 6' 8''. Likewise, the 
>      maximum allowable weight is 44 lbs.**
> 7. **Un-evolved Pokemon only. Description: Only un-evolved Pokemon
>      may be used.**
> 8. No two Pokemon asleep or frozen. Description: If one Pokemon falls
>      asleep, none of the others can be put
>      to  sleep by an opponent. The same
>      goes for freezing. It is possible to
>      have one  Pokemon asleep and another
>      frozen.
> 9. Mew can't attend. Description: Mew may be used only for the Gym Leader
>      Castle, Prime Cup, and  Free Battle.
> 10. Get a continue for a perfect match. Description: You earn a
>       continue for every battle won without
>       a fainted  Pokemon. If you have a
>       continue, you may try again after
>       losing a battle.
> 11. No Selfdestruct move with last Pokemon. Description: If your last
>       remaining Pokemon uses Selfdestruct or
>       Explosion,  you lose, even if the
>       opponent's last Pokemon faints.

Comment: That's really interesting, thanks. Slightly frustrating, but it will be fun to come up with an appropriate level team that meets the requirements. Cheers.